# Cannot run debug Go using VSCode on Mac M1

Tags: go, visual-studio-code, vscode-debugger, apple-m1

I found a topic that encounter the same problem ([Can't debug Golang in vscode apple m1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67637872/cant-debug-golang-in-vscode-apple-m1)) but I'm not sure it's an old solution or not because I'm using the Go version

```
go1.17.1 darwin/arm64
```

with

```
dlv version 1.7.2
```

and

```
VSCode version 1.60.2 (arm64)
```

on

```
Mac M1 BigSur (11.6)
```

when I run debug (`fn+f5`) a Debug console shows:

```
Starting: /Users/username/go/bin/dlv-dap dap --check-go-version=false --listen=127.0.0.1:53115 --log-dest=3 from /Users/username/go/src/project-name
DAP server listening at: 127.0.0.1:53115
```

and there is a Pop-up error:

```
Failed to launch: could not launch process: can not run under Rosetta, check that the installed build of Go is right for your CPU architecture
```

I have tried downgrade go version to 1.16.8 arm64 with dlv 1.6.1 but still got the same error.

I can use go build successfully on both versions.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

1. Ensure your VSCode uses the arm64 version. (it can use a different
   go version from the system)
2. Run Go: install/update tools. It will rebuild all tools with the arm64 go version.

Comment: could you elaborate on this? "Ensure your VSCode uses the arm64 version" ... how?

Comment: @PeterMcIntyre what I did is observe the location of the dlv-dap command vscode was using (Note "Starting: /Users/username/go/bin/dlv-dap ..." in the question), then verified this was the same go I had configured in the PATH/command-line using 'which go' (it can be different, AFAIK vscode bases on the GOPATH go env variable). Running "go version" I saw I was using darwin/amd64, NOT ARM. I downloaded the correct version from https://go.dev/dl/ and replaced it (by removing the whole 'go' directory and placing the new one in its place)

Comment: Thanks! Command-Shift-P > "Go: Install/update tools" fixed it for me! Had installed the amd64 instead of arm64 version before and removing and installing the correct version of go wasn't enough as the tools were still for the intel processor!

Answer (score 39):

Here is how I resolved this issue.

1. [Uninstall Golang](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57634196/4408364)(AMD-64 version).
2. Install Golang(ARM-64). Confirm it with `go env GOARCH`
3. Remove(tools that VS-Code uses) binaries from `$GOPATH/bin` (**Important**)
4. Restart your VS-Code and install tools that VS-Code needed(if not installed vscode will complain and will ask you to install them)

**Root cause of the problem**: I accidentally installed `amd-64` version instead of `arm-64` version in my `Apple Mac M1`.

Thanks to [Painhardcore](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69353947/4408364) answer for pointing me in right direction.

Comment: the installed libraries was it for me. I have had both correct packages installed for a bit but I must have installed the wrong Golang for a while early on. I just needed to clear the old binaries and reinstall them

Comment: thanks, that helped! small note here, as of 1.18 it seems `$GOPATH/bin` is not in use anymore, rather use `~/go/bin`. see https://stackoverflow.com/a/44506125/5065201

Comment: It felt dangerous to me to remove all binaries in `go/bin`, but it seems like VSCode re-creates them without problems.

Comment: You can also reinstall the tools that VS Code uses by
1. press F1 and
2. `Go: Install/Update Tools`
3. Select tools you want to reinstall

Comment: @iamcmnut's comment is gold.

Comment: agreed @iamcmnut saved me - I did the full reinstall of go - was able to run tests within vscode - but couldn't debug.  If I tried to debug - I got that same error "can not run under Rosetta".  After reinstall of vs code Go Tools - I was able to debug again.  Thanks!

Comment: Is it worth an update to the instruction not to mention $GOPATH/bin? An unsuspecting person trying `sudo rm $GOPATH/bin` may have an unpleasant surprise.

Answer (score 9):

What worked for me:

1. Check for "chip" your mac is using, you can check that from `"About This Mac" > "Overview" > "Chip"`
2. If Apple chip is used, then download "arm64" type of files, such as "go-darwin-arm64.pkg", "vscode-arm64" etc. You get my point.
3. If Intel chip is used, then download with "amd" type.
4. Download and install "DELVE" from https://github.com/go-delve/delve/tree/master/Documentation/installation
5. Run your debugger.

Let me know, if you want the "launch.json" file config too, to debug.

**EDIT 11-04-22**

Sharing the launch.json

```
{
    // Use IntelliSense to learn about possible attributes.
    // Hover to view descriptions of existing attributes.
    // For more information, visit: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=830387
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "Debug",
            "type": "go",
            "request": "launch",
            "mode": "auto",
            "program": "${workspaceFolder}/main.go",
            "args": [],
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: Can you post the launch.json please?

Comment: Hi @Ryan, I have shared the launch.json, check for the edit.

Answer (score 3):

This answer worked for me. Installed ARM64 and tried again.

https://github.com/go-delve/delve/issues/2604#issuecomment-1069740132

Comment: This helped me resolve it after so much effort. Thanks

Comment: My issue was that I didn't install gdlv, but with your help it worked!

Answer (score 3):

#### ✅ SOLUTION ✅

The issue is that you had installed the non-M1 version of GoLang and/or VSCode.
There are versions for Intel and Apple chips of both Go and VSCode. You need both to be the arm64 (Apple Silicon) version

If you didn't install both GoLang and VSCode using the arm64 distribution then that is where the problem is.

**To fix this issue**:

- Completely remove GoLang and VSCode from your system:

  - ***Remove GoLang completely***:

    - `sudo rm -rf /usr/local/go`
    - `sudo rm /etc/paths.d/go`
    - `sudo rm -rf ~/donald/go` *(replace `donald` with your own account name)*

      - (removing this is the   to fixing your issue)
  - ***Remove VSCode completely***:

    - `rm -fr ~/Library/Preferences/com.microsoft.VSCode.helper.plist`
    - `rm -fr ~/Library/Preferences/com.microsoft.VSCode.plist`
    - `rm -fr ~/Library/Caches/com.microsoft.VSCode`
    - `rm -fr ~/Library/Caches/com.microsoft.VSCode.ShipIt/`
    - `rm -fr ~/Library/Application\ Support/Code/`
    - `rm -fr ~/Library/Saved\ Application\ State/com.microsoft.VSCode.savedState/`
    - `rm -fr ~/.vscode/`
- Download the arm64 version of each GoLang and VSCode.

  - [GoLang download page](https://go.dev/dl/) -❗make sure it says ***arm64*** (it ***can't*** be AMD64) ❗
  - [VS Code for macOS download page](https://code.visualstudio.com/download) - ❗make sure it says ***Apple Silicon*** (it ***can't*** be Universal nor Intel)❗
- Install GoLang
- Install VSCode
- Open VSCode.
- Install the [Go extension](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/languages/go)
- Open a GoLang project/directory.
- It will ask you to install the Go tools (like 8 or so tools). Just click "Install All"

  ```bash
  Installing 8 tools at /Users/donald/go/bin in module mode.
  gotests
  gomodifytags
  impl
  goplay
  dlv
  staticcheck
  gopls
  go-outline
  ```
- Open a `.go` file that you want to run.
- Run it using VS Code.

That's it! You should be good to go now

Answer (score 1):

Download and install `DELVE` from https://github.com/go-delve/delve/tree/master/Documentation/installation

It worked for me

Answer (score 0):

Writing this so that anyone facing same problem while migrating to M1 mac can get all the required information at one place.

I faced this issue after migrating data from my intel mac to M1(using Apple Migration Assistant).
So basically, the go binaries and vscode for amd64 were copied to M1 mac(arm64)

Hence, i had to uninstall (removed all go related files i.e located at `/home/<my_user>/go` and go executables located at `/usr/local/go`) and reinstall go and vscode for arm64.

Post that, i was getting the error `could not launch process: EOF` while running the debugger in vscode using delve, to solve that i referred to this github thread - https://github.com/go-delve/delve/issues/2794

and performed below steps:

```
sudo rm -rf /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools

xcode-select --install
```

After that, i was able to use delve to debug code in vscode

Answer (score 0):

The main Go install page (https://go.dev/doc/install) offers you a "download" button which is AMD64.  You have to go here:
https://go.dev/dl/

and select the correct architecture.  Once you've done that you need to uninstall as already mentioned by @prakash-p.

And then you'll also need to reinstall go tools in vs code as mentioned by @iamcmnut