# VSCode Debugger not working under Rosetta

Tags: go, vscode-debugger, foundationdb

when trying to use the VSCode Debugger, I get an error message:

`"Failed to launch: could not launch process: can not run under Rosetta, check that the installed build of Go is right for your CPU architecture"`

some background context as I read solutions for similar questions:

- I use foundationDB which does not work with GO arm64
- For this reason, I am using GO amd64
- Switching to arm64 would mean that foundationDB will not work, which is not an option

I tried downloading dlv, but it doesn't work. Also tried the solution proposed [here](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/428782/how-to-run-vscode-integrated-terminal-in-x86-64-on-apple-m1-arm64) to run VSCode integrated terminal in x86-64.

Is there a way for the debugger to work with Apple M1 using go1.18 darwin/amd64?

Comment: Have you tried installing Homebrew in Rosetta mode (https://stackoverflow.com/a/64883440/5547232) and installing it through that?

Answer (score 10):

I just got this issue on my M1 and was able to resolve. Here are my steps:

- go to the go download page, https://go.dev/dl/ and download the arm version of go installer. Specifically, go.darwin-**arm64**.pkg
- install go, if it detects a previous version, agree to replace
- open terminal and verify go version and it should say "go version go **darwin/arm64**"
- On VSCode, click on plugins, find the installed Go plugin, and uninstall then reload VSCode.
- When the plugin installation is complete, press Ctrl + Shift + P in VSCode to bring up the Command Palette, then type go: Install and select go: Install/Update Tools, then click the first checkbox to install all Tools.
- When Go Tools install is complete, reload VSCode and retry breakpoint.

Answer (score 0):

This is a popular issue on Mac. The solution is to install **Golang** and **VSCODE** in ARM-64 (not AMD64).

Here are some links for reference

https://github.com/go-delve/delve/issues/2604

[Cannot run debug Go using VSCode on Mac M1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69343900/cannot-run-debug-go-using-vscode-on-mac-m1)

Comment: It seems that switching to arm64 is not an option here. Any idea how to continue using the AMD Go lib?